# Calculate the value of c for which f is a probability density.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let f the function defined by:

[image]Where c is positive none zero and constant .

How can i calculate the value of c for which f is a probability density.Thnxs for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is a probability density function over the triangular region $$T=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2:0<x<2, |y|<x\}$$ if $f(x,y)\ge 0$ and 
$I=\iint_T f(x,y)\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y=1$. Evidently $f(x,y)\ge 0$ if $c\ge0$.
Observing that the domain $T$ is normal with respect to the $x$-axis, and $f$ is a continuous function, then
$$I=\iint_T f(x,y)\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y=c\int_0^2\underbrace{\left(\int_{-x}^x x(x-y)\operatorname{d}y\right)}_{2x^3}\operatorname{d}x=2c\int_0^2 x^3\operatorname{d}x=8c$$
so that $I=1$ if $c=\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the value if you solve
$$
\int \int f dx dy = 1
$$

Comment: ok i will do it thanks

Comment: I need to solve $\int \int f dx dy = 1 = x (c_1+f y)+c_2$ is that correct?